# Is there a way to access the built-in excel form via a shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2016, forms

Is there a way to access the built-in excel form via a shortcut? Macros/VBA and addins are disabled. Users are running either Excel 2013 or Excel 2016.

Search has yielded only custom toolbar solutions or macro/vba solutions so far. The toolbar customization has been rejected since this is for non-tech savvy c-suite end users. Macros are a no-go because they are disabled by IT w/o exceptions. Thanks so much.

Comment: mind to share a sample of "built-in excel form" that you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said data form

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the data form, it is no longer automatically on the toolbar menu but you can add it yourself.
Excel help provides these directions

Add the Form button to the Quick Access Toolbar

1.Click the arrow next to the Quick Access Toolbar, and then click More Commands.

2.In the Choose commands from box, click All Commands.

3.In the list box, select the Form button Form Control button , and then click Add.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the data form. My original thought was to have users add the button to their quick access toolbar, but that was rejected. I'm thinking there is no other way w/o using a macro or add-in